# Scope of SwiftUI Animations

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

Experimenting with SwiftUI animations and it's taxing my old grey matter.  I'm getting different results for two very similar variants of code, and can't work out why.

Example: The below produces a vertical stack of three images.

```
@State private var rotationAmount = 0.0

VStack{        
  ForEach(0..<3) { number in
    Button {
      rotationAmount += 360
      //execute main functionality
    } label: {
      MyImage(number)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAmount), anchor: .center)                        
    }
  }
}
```

When one of the images (i.e. buttons) is clicked its image spins 360 deg on its Z axis

However if the button action code is changed so it uses a `withAnimation` block the behaviour is different:

```
    Button{
      withAnimation {
        rotationAmount += 360
      }
      //execute main functionality
    } label: {
      MyImage(number)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAmount), anchor: .center)                        
    }
```

With this variation clicking any of the images results in all three of them spinning.

In both cases every button has an animation bound to the `rotationAmount` property, so I don't understand the difference in behaviour between the two examples.  If anything I'd expect all three images to spin in both situations as they are all bounds to the same mutating property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time `rotationAmount` changes it causes the `ContentView`s body to get reevaluated. Due to `360` being added to `rotationAmount` each time, we wouldn't expect there to be any visible changes when there's no animation as the view would be rotated around to the exact position it's in.

To see this you could replace `.rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAmount), anchor: .center)` with `.font(rotationAmount == 0.0 ? .body : .largeTitle)`, this will show you that all the views get updated, just some without an animation.

```
Button {
    rotationAmount += 360
} label: {
    MyImage(number)
        .font(rotationAmount == 0.0 ? .body : .largeTitle)                      
}
```

The behavior of `Button` when being tapped is what is causing one image to rotate with animation without explicitly telling it to do so. Due to the highlight state of the button causing animated changes to the label of the button, animations are also applied to other changes that occur to the button at the same time.

To see that it's caused by the image being in a button label specifically you could use `.onTapGesture` to see that it won't update when it's not in the button label:

```
MyImage(number)
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAmount), anchor: .center)
    .onTapGesture {
        rotationAmount += 360
    }
```

You can also see that it's caused by other animations occurring to the button label at the same time, the code below will cause the `rotationEffect` change to occur once the button highlighted state has finished animating, resulting in the image not animating when the property changes:

```
Button {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
        rotationAmount += 360
    })
} label: {
    MyImage(number)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAmount), anchor: .center)
}
```

Here's an example shows that using `withAnimation` to update one property and not placing the other property change inside `withAnimation` will cause only the property in the `withAnimation` block to animate when the button is tapped:

```
Button {
    rotationAmount += 360

    withAnimation {
        myColorEnabled.toggle() // @State var myColorEnabled = false
    }
} label: {
    Text("Test")
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotationAmount), anchor: .center)
    Text("Hello")
        .foregroundColor(myColorEnabled ? .red : .gray)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer - it filled in a couple of gaps in how swiftUI works. (It's far too easy to use, adding pieces like a jigsaw, without understanding the underlying mechanics; something that never wa an option in UIKit)